# Web Api route {id:int}.xlsx is not found

Tags: c#, rest, owin, asp.net-web-api2, attributerouting

I have an API endpoint that shall export some data as an Excel xlsx file. The URL I try to get is like this: `localhost/service/resources/123.xlsx` (because I think using this extension is a nice way to do it).
But it always gives me a 404 Not Found.

The controller has a route prefix: `[RoutePrefix("resources")]` and the route attribute on the action is: `[Route("{id:int}.xlsx")]`

Even when I changed the route to `[Route("123.xlsx")]` it would not find it. I also tried a regex constraint `[Route("{key:regex(\\d+\\.xlsx}")]` with no luck.

I suspect it may be grabbed by static file handler, but the web config already has the setting

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
```

I believe this should work, because it worked for a very similar route in a previous project, using the old routing setup and not attribute routing. That project was not hosted using OWIN, but is that the problem here?

How can I make this work? I need this route for both GET and PUT.

Btw, `localhost/service/resources/123` will return a different representation of the resource.

**Info: Hosted in IIS 7.5 using OWIN 3.0 and Web API 5.2.2**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out [here](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-middleware-in-the-iis-integrated-pipeline) that adding this line of code

```
app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.MapHandler);
```

**after**

```
app.UseWebApi()
```

in the `Startup` class made it work!

(I don't actually understand exactly what it does, but hey, who cares)